# Cannot delete SSL certificate in Azure

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I am unable to delete app service certificate. I get the error "Please remove the lock and try again”. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resource Manager Locks provide a way for administrators to lock down Azure resources to prevent deletion or changing of a resource.

If you want to delete a certificate that has been locked, Navigate to Locks in App Service certificate and delete it before attempting to delete the certificate:

Go to Azure Portal -> App Service Certificate -> select your certificate-> you will see locks page with in the overview-> Select the lock held on the desired cert name-> Hit delete as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your assistance.